# creating a simulation game,  what type of knowledge is needed?

Tags: javascript, html5

I am a beginner in game development. As a part of learning and fun, want to create a game in java-script and html5. I am planning a game that we were used to play in childhood, that is "new business"- a monopoly game, in that we used to buy ,rent,sell places and bank we get some money to play and etc. are features. Its just simple ludo like game.

So can anyone suggest me from where to start? what will be the designing?

Is it possible to create it only in a html5 and java-script.

Comment: Hi Jordan and welcome to the site. Unfortunately this question is overly broad and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying what questions to ask, please see the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Our FAQ on ["What kind of questions can I ask here?"](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) explicitly states "how do I get started" questions as disallowed. There are plenty of books, tutorials, etc. to get you started, and it really starts with your own motivation to seek those out. Please feel free to ask better questions according to the FAQ once you do get started!

Comment: Sorry. I am a layman. U can help me to get me improve my grammar. :)

Comment: @Jordan I see you are indeed not a native speaker, I apologize. "What is needed?" or "what might be needed?" would be correct. If this were not a closed question I would edit to fix its grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very broad question, so I'm not sure there is any right answer.

An equally broad answer: try to make a simple prototype of your game - no fancy graphics and animations or such things, just the core gameplay. Then you test this (maybe let some other people test it as well), and see if that gameplay is fun, what is good and bad about it. Then you improve on that, test again, and repeat this process until you have something that you think will work well as a game.

Then you have two options:

1. The quick&dirty way: take your existing prototype and add graphics, animations, sounds etc. to it. That's quick&dirty in so far as you probably changed your code quite often during the improvement/testing iterations, and it's probably not very clean as a result. But it may be good enough for you.
2. Rewrite your game with all the knowledge you now have about what you want to do and how to do it. Keep everything clean and organized, and in the process also add in graphics and all the other stuff.

That's all I can say until you ask more specific questions.